# Is simple straight-edge and compass construction a substantial proof?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

I'm working on a problem that asks to prove that a point $D$ is outside of a $\triangle ABC$, on the circle through the triangle, given that sides $AB$ and $AC$ are not congruent, and that $D$ is the point of intersection between the line bisecting $\angle A$ and the perpendicular bisector of side $BC$. I constructed in with a straight-edge and compass, and $D$ appears to be outside of the triangle and on its circle. Does showing the construction for it suffice as a proof or is there some other way that I should be proving it?

Comment: What do you mean with "is indeed ... on its circle"? You tried a single random triangle and worked as diligently as possible and could not find a visual distance between the pencil mark for the point and the circle with your naked eye?

Comment: Not if you just did one example, and didn't prove it in general, no. Why would you think doing a single construction can prove something for all possible triangles with $AB$ and $AC$ not congruent? How did you even show that $D$ was on the circle in your construction - might it not have been just close enough to the circle to appear to be on the circle?

Comment: That two sides in a triangle "are not congruent" means their lengths are different, i.e. $\;|AB|\neq |AC|\;$ ?

Comment: It appears by "on its circle" you mean "inside its circle"?

Comment: That's the usual meaning of not congruent, @DonAntonio. Since, if they were the same length, the angle bisector is the same as the perpendicular bisector of the opposite side, that's another hint that is the expected meaning.

Comment: Since the straight-edge and compass construction picture you created was just a single model of all possibilities, it does not suffice as a proof. There were probably a lot of arbitrary decisions you made on your own outside of the hypotheses, for example, the positions of $A,B$ and $C$.

To prove it, you're going to have to appeal to facts about the elements given to you in the hypotheses.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, here we use "congruent" to mean the whole triangle/square/parallelogram etc.. For single straight segments or angles we use "equal" or not "equal".

Answer (score 1):

Show that the other point of intersection of the bisector of $\angle A$ and the circle exactly halves the arc $BC$. Also show that the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $BC$ exactly halves the arc $BC$.
Conclude that the midpoint of arc $BC$ is the point of intersection.

Comment: How would I begin to prove that they half the arc $BC$?

Comment: Inscribed angle theorem?